# variable in try clause not accessible in finally clause - python

Tags: python, mysql-python

I am new to python, so sorry if this question is dumb, but can someone tell me what's going on here.

When I run the following code with no errors in the mdb.connect() call, the code runs fine.

But when I purposely insert an error (for example, put in 'localhostblahblah'), I get a 'NameError: name 'con' is not defined' error when I execute.

I thought that variables defined in the try clause should be accessible in the finally clause. What's going on?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import MySQLdb as mdb
import sys

try:
    con = mdb.connect('localhost','jmtoung','','ptb_genetics')

except mdb.Error, e:
    print "Error"
    sys.exit(1)

finally:
    if con:
        con.close()
```

Comment: What would you expect to happen?

Answer (score 10):

If `mdb.connect` errors, there's nothing to assign to `con`, so it doesn't get defined.

Instead of `finally`, try using `else`, which is run only when there was no exception.  [Docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)

```
try:
    con = mdb.connect('localhost','jmtoung','','ptb_genetics')

except mdb.Error as e:
    print "Error"
    sys.exit(1)

else:  # else instead of finally
    con.close()
```

Comment: I always forget that you can use `else` like that in Python. It also works on `while` and `for` loops, as I remember.

Comment: They just love throwing `else` into everything, don't they?

Comment: Would you write that as `except mdb.Error as e`? It's a much clearer syntax and works in both Python 2.6+ and Python 3.

Comment: @KirkStrauser, yes I personally would. hadn't inspected the less pertinent code. updated

Answer (score 1):

Do it [EAFP](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp) style:

```
try: con = mdb.connect('localhost','jmtoung','','ptb_genetics')
except mdb.Error, e: #handle it
finally:
    try: con.close()
    except NameError: pass # it failed to connect
    except: raise # otherwise, raise that exception because it failed to close
```

Answer (score 0):

If an error occurs in the process of variable assignment, the variable will not be assigned to.

```
>>> x = 3
>>> try:
...     x = open(r'C:\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
... finally:
...     print(x)
...     
3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 2, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
```